# How to choose name of Foreign Key column using Sequelize and mySql?

Tags: mysql, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

I am using sequelize to model a mySql-database schema in my node-application. An extract of my model looks like this:
I have a company-table and a department-table. A company can have multiple departments and a department belongs to only one company. I modeled this as follows:

The company-table:

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes){
return Company = sequelize.define('Company', {
    companyId: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        unique: true            
    },
    name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    }
})}
```

The department-table:

```
var Company = require('./company');

module.exports = function(sequelize,DataTypes) {
return Department = sequelize.define('Department', {
    departmentId: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        unique: true
    },
    name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false            
    },
    companyId: {
        type:           DataTypes.INTEGER,
        references:     'Companies',
        referencesKey:  'companyId',
        onDelete:       'cascade'
    }
});}
```

To actually store this schema in the database I use the following code:

```
var db = require('../models/index');
db["Company"].hasMany(db["Department"], {as: 'departments'});
db["Department"].belongsTo(db["Company"], {foreignKey: 'companyId', foreignKeyConstraint: true});

models.sequelize.sync().complete(function(err){
    //irrelevant for the problem
});
```

The problem is that this code creates 2 foreign keys in the department table. One on the field "companyId" (as expected) but also one on the field "CompanyCompanyId", a field that is automatically generated.

How can I make sure that only the foreign key I defined ('companyId') is used and created?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I managed to fix the problem:

Instead of only using the "foreignKey"-option in the belongsTo-statement, it should also be used in the "hasMany"-statement.

The two models that were posted in the original question remained the same. The only thing I had to change was the location of the foreignKey option:

```
var db = require('../models/index');
db["Company"].hasMany(db["Department"], {as: 'departments'});
db["Department"].belongsTo(db["Company"], {foreignKey: 'companyId', foreignKeyConstraint: true});
```

changed to:

```
var db = require('../models/index');
db["Company"].hasMany(db["Department"], { foreignKey: 'companyId'});
db["Department"].belongsTo(db["Company"], {foreignKey: 'companyId'});
```

Comment: Yes, same foreignKey value on both sides of relationship solves the problem, thanks!

Comment: If you have additional options for the `foreignKey` (e.g. `allowNull: false`) then you can specify its name using `name`: `foreignKey: {name: 'companyId', allowNull: false}`.

Comment: Hi Simon am struggling to create foreign key can you help me?

Answer (score 8):

In the version 4.4.0, there is a targetKey option for the belongsTo function.

```
const User = this.sequelize.define('user', {/* attributes */})
const Company  = this.sequelize.define('company', {/* attributes */});

User.belongsTo(Company, {foreignKey: 'fk_companyname', targetKey: 'name'}); // Adds fk_companyname to User
```

more information on http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/associations.html#target-keys

Answer (score 4):

I know this thread is somewhat old, but I stumbled upon it when having problems declaring a 1:n association. I am using sequelize 5.21.5. The way to reference keys in the attributes changed from (borrowed from your example):

```
companyId: {
  type:           DataTypes.INTEGER,
  references:     'Companies',
  referencesKey:  'companyId'
}
```

to:

```
companyId: {
  type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
  references: {
    model: 'Company',
    key: 'companyId'
  }
}
```

Hope this helps any weary traveler along the way!

Answer (score 1):

Sequelize creates foreignKey field for you. So no need to define field `companyId` in `Department` model, if you are using `belongsTo`.

In current scenario it will create two foreign keys one defined in model and another via `belongsTo` and when it tries to create foreignKey again it finds that field already exists so it creates another field.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I noticed that sequelize creates a foreignKey field for me. It is called "CompanyCompanyId", but I would like to be able to give it a name that I defined (i.e. "companyId" instead of "CompanyCompanyId"). Do you know how I can achieve this?

Comment: You can specify it using `as` in options. Ex. `db["Department"].belongsTo(db["Company"], {as: 'companyId', foreignKey: 'companyId', foreignKeyConstraint: true});`

Comment: Thanks for your input Nilesh but I managed to fix it otherwise. Check my own reply to know how I did it.